# What parts of firebase.auth response should be stored locally (in reactjs app)? What do they do?

Tags: firebase, react-native

Following docs for authenticating users in firebase for authentication and DB access in a react-native app via firebase package (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth (following this tutorial: https://medium.com/dailyjs/react-native-email-authentication-with-firebase-4be20142b0a9)), am now at a point where I have a successful firebase auth response object from the code

```
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((res) => { 
        console.log(`Login successful: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`)
        //TODO: signin stuff, eg. storing user session credentials?
        this.props.navigation.navigate('MainNav')
    })
    .catch((res) => {
        console.log(`Login was not successful: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`)
        this.setState({signinError: res.message})
    });
```

of the form

```
    Object {
       "apiKey": "qwerty",
       "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
       "authDomain": "myapp-z12345.firebaseapp.com",
       "createdAt": "1531206612000",
       "displayName": null,
       "email": "me@gmail.com",
       "emailVerified": false,
       ...
       "stsTokenManager": Object {
            "accessToken":"qwerty",
            "apiKey": "qwerty",
            "expirationTime": 1531339781120,
            "refreshToken": "qwerty",
       },
       "uid": "qwerty123",
     }
```

My question is: what am I supposed to do with these values? What do the different tokens do (totally new to firebase and moblie apps)? Which should be stored and which should be accessed some other way?

Looking at the firebase docs, I don't see any token being used to access firebase DB (I'm actually using firestore, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart), so I'm a bit confused about their use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.onAuthStateChanged` (asynchronous) to handle the authentication state of your app. You don't need to do anything with those values other than get the `currentUser.uid`. Firebase.auth handles all that stuff for you. If you want to store user info, you should collect that separate via a form and store it under a `users/uid` node in your datastore - maybe firstName, lastName, birthday, favoriteColor, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the [@Ron Royston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293524/2315280), you can always retrieve the same information with using [`currentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#currentUser). In some cases like if your users logging in with a social account, you might need to access the `accessToken` or similar part of that provider's information to do an API call or something. In these cases again you can use `currentUser` to get the desired information so you don't need to store anything from there.

That information mostly provided for some checks like if the mail is verified, if not send a verification mail or show a notification, check how did the user logged in, social or email, do some special actions if necessary etc.